# Fields does not Update in laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

I am working on Laravel Form data Updation with image update. Now here my image only update smoothly in my DB. But other field does not update. anyone can identify what is my mistake? i attached my code below:

Controller

```
    public function siteadmin_update_ads(Request $request)
    {


       $post = $request->all(); 
        $cid=$post['id'];  
        $name = $post['ads_title'];
        $url = $post['ads_url'];
        $img=Input::file('ads_image');;

        $v=validator::make($request->all(),
                [
                    'ads_title'=>'required',
                    'ads_url' => 'required',
                    'ads_image'=> 'required'
                ]
                );

        if($v->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
        }



        else 

            {
            if($img->isvalid())
            {
                $extension=$img->getClientOriginalName();
                $move_img = explode('.',$extension);
                $fileName=$move_img[0].str_random(8).".".$move_img[1];
                $destinationPath = '../assets/adsimage/';



                $uploadSuccess=Input::file('ads_image')->move($destinationPath,$fileName);

            $data=array(

                'ads_title'=> $name,
                'ads_url'=>   $url,
                'ads_image'=>$fileName,

            );

            $i=Ads_model::update_ads($data,$cid);

            if($i>0)
            {
                Session::flash ('message_update', 'Record Updated Successfully');
                return redirect('siteadmin_manageads');
            }
        }

             else {
 return Redirect('siteadmin_editads');
}   
}
}
```

Model

```
public static function update_ads($data,$cid)
    {
      return DB::table('le_ads')->where('id',$cid)->update($data);  
    }
```

View

```
  <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" id="myform" novalidate method="POST" action="{{action('SiteadminController@siteadmin_update_ads')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

               <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo    csrf_token(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id  ?>" id="id">
                                    <div class="item form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Ad Title<span class="required">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <input id="name" class="form- control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="3" name="ads_title"  placeholder="Ad Title" required type="text" value="<?php echo $row->ads_title ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    <div class="item form-group">
                                          <label class="control-label col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Upload Image*</label>
                                      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <input type='file' id="field" class='demo left' name='ads_image' data-type='image' data-max-size='2mb'/><br>
                                        <img src="{{ url('../assets/adsimage/').'/'.$row->ads_image}}" style="height:90px;">
                                        </div>
                            </div>

                                  <div class="item form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Redirect URL<span class="required">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="3" name="ads_url" placeholder="Redirect URL" required type="url" value="<?php echo $row->ads_url ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                                  <div class="item form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                                <button class="btn btn-block btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" type="reset">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                         </div>


                  </form>
```

Comment: Have you try to look on laravel.log?

Comment: no.. how to look laravel.log?

Comment: it is on storage/logs/laravel.log